# Cassandra version 3.11.2 counter updates are always null

Tags: cassandra

I am running Cassandra 3.11.2 and the counter columns are always null. Here are the steps I am doing.

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.test (
page_id int,
page_name Text,
page_count counter,
PRIMARY KEY ((page_id, page_name))
);

UPDATE myschema.test SET page_count = page_count + 1  where page_id =  
2 and page_name = 'test.com'  ;

SELECT * FROM myschema.test ;
2,"test.com",""
```

I am doing the basic example and it seems to be not working. Any thoughts?.

Comment: I'm not sure from the update query what the select is meant to return. Does something like the following match the logic of your code? If not, what do you expect the select to return? update myschema.test set page_count = page_count + 1  where page_id = 1a435da1-a091-4a1c-92b9-efab881b04ca and page_name ='test.com' and insertion_time =dateof(now());

Comment: You should update your original question with the above information. Also, any other information regarding your environment, would be good. I tried to reproduce the issue, but it for me the update was successful. I tried on a ccm cluster, 3.11.2, 1 node.

Comment: This seems to work (I think your keyspace name in the select is just a typo, but check that). Can you share the definition of the keyspace "myschema"? CREATE TABLE myschema.test ( page_id int, page_name Text, page_count counter, PRIMARY KEY ((page_id, page_name)) ); 
update myschema.test set page_count = page_count + 1 where page_id = 2 and page_name = 'test.com' ; 
select * from myschema.test ;

Comment: @ValerieParham-Thompson : here is the create keyspace command I have used:      CREATE KEYSPACE myschema WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;

Comment: OK, thanks. Your definitions and queries are working for me (docker containers running 3.11.2). Agree with Horia... can you share some more information about your environment? Especially what interface are you using to query?

Comment: @ValerieParham-Thompson & Horia  you both are correct. The counters are working as expected. I was using a tool called TablePlus and it was showing  null values. When I use CSQL, it works as expected. Thanks you.